# Which CSS files should I edit to make any simple color/style changes in this template?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, templates

I'm working a bit on this Bootstrap template (SB Admin 2) https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/ and I would like to know if it's possible to edit any css file to change, for example, some background color like the typical light grey or the white one, I've tried already some files like bootstrap.css, bootstrap-min.css, and the other CSS files inside the bower_components folder, but can't get any visible change, and since the HTML has correctly all the navbar classes, I think I should get easily the color changes applying them to the respective classes on the CSS files.

Thank you all so much in advance, meanwhile, I'll continue researching what I can do to get some style changes!

Comment: CSS = Cascading Style Sheets. Just add your own custom CSS file after that one loads and override the desired rules. They will need to be at least as specific as the rules you're trying to override.

Comment: @DanWeber Thanks for answering, for example, using the !important property, am I then overriding the other file's specific rules? Thanks!

Comment: @DanWeber already working, should have thought about it before.. :( Thanks so much again!

Comment: No problem. Also, just an FYI, using !important is bad practice. If it's not working without the !important then either you are not being specific enough with your rule. i.e. #divId > .some-class {} is more specific than .some-class {}

Comment: I see, thanks again @DanWeber, i'll remember these tips and put them into practice! Fortunately, without the !important, everything on the new CSS file is working properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From question comments

> CSS = Cascading Style Sheets. Just add your own custom CSS file after
>   that one loads and override the desired rules. They will need to be at
>   least as specific as the rules you're trying to override.